# Entity Framework - Problema na associação de relacionamento 1 para 0..1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou com problema de associação entre duas tabelas.

Tabelas Aluno e Aluno_Unidade_Curso.

```
Public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int cod_aluno { get; set; }
    ........
    public virtual Aluno_Unidade_Curso Aluno_Unidade_Curso { get; set; }
 }

Public class Aluno_Unidade_Curso
{
    [Key,Column("cod_aluno_unidade_curso",Order =0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key,ForeignKey("Aluno")]
    public int cod_aluno { get; set; }
    ........
    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
 }


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno_Unidade_Curso>().HasRequired(auc => auc.Aluno).WithRequiredPrincipal(auc => auc.Aluno_Unidade_Curso); 
 }
```

Quando carrego o objeto Aluno a associação iguala o código do Aluno (cod_aluno) com o Id do tabela Aluno_Unidade_Curso (Id) e não com a FK (cod_aluno)

Estou iniciando em MVC 5.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua modelagem está errada.

Uma unidade de curso deve ser registrada em outro lugar, como por exemplo numa entidade `UnidadeCurso`:

```
public class UnidadeCurso
{
    [Key]
    public int UnidadeCursoId { get; set; }
    public int CursoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Curso Curso { get; set; }
}
```

E `Curso`:

```
public class Curso
{
    [Key]
    public int CursoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<UnidadeCurso> UnidadesCurso { get; set; }
}
```

Assim, podemos associar o `Aluno` a uma `UnidadeCurso`:

```
public class AlunoUnidadeCurso
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoUnidadeCursoId { get; set; }
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public int UnidadeCursoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
    public virtual UnidadeCurso UnidaderCurso { get; set; }
}
```

Claro que você vai precisar atualizar seu `Aluno`:

```
public class Aluno
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    ........
    public virtual IEnumerable<AlunoUnidadeCurso> AlunoUnidadesCurso { get; set; }
}
```

E `UnidadeCurso` também:

```
public class UnidadeCurso
{
    [Key]
    public int UnidadeCursoId { get; set; }
    public int CursoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Curso Curso { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<AlunoUnidadeCurso> AlunoUnidadesCurso { get; set; }
}
```